# couldn't find file 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fusioncharts

We followed this link for Fusion Charts
http://www.fusioncharts.com/ruby-on-rails-charts/

We are getting this error
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Dashboard#index
couldn't find file 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts' with type 'application/javascript'

Answer (score 1):

Once you have downloaded and extracted files from the package:

Copy the JavaScript files in to the vendor/assets/javascripts/fusioncharts/ folder.

Add the following code lines in the app/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts
//= require fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint
```